# Scala: batch process Map of index-based form fields

Tags: scala, binding, indexing, field, numeric

Part of a web app I'm working on handles forms that need to be bound to a collection of model (case class) instances. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662653/play-2-idiomatic-approach-to-binding-a-form-to-listmodel)

So, if I were to add several users at one time, form fields would be named `email[0]`, `email[1]`, `password[0]`, `password[1]`, etc.

Posting the form results in a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`

Now, what I would like to do is to process the Map in batches, by index, so that for each iteration I can bind a User instance, creating a `List[User]` as the final result of the bindings.

The hacked approach I'm thinking of is to regex match against `"[\d]"` in the Map keys and then find the highest index via filter or count; with that, then `(0..n).toList map{ ?? }` through the number of form field rows, calling the binding/validation method (which also takes a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`) accordingly.

What is a concise way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. All map keys are in form `"field[index]"`
2. There is only one value in `Seq` for each key.
3. If there is entry for `"email[x]"` than there is entry for `"password[x]"` and vice versa.

I would done something like this:

```
val request = Map(
  "email[0]" -> Seq("alice@example.com"),
  "email[1]" -> Seq("bob@example.com"),
  "password[0]" -> Seq("%vT*n7#4"),
  "password[1]" -> Seq("Bfts7B&^")
)

case class User(email: String, password: String)

val Field = """(.+)\[(\d+)\]""".r

val userList = request.groupBy { case (Field(_, idx), _) => idx.toInt }
                      .mapValues { userMap =>
                          def extractField(name: String) =
                              userMap.collect{case (Field(`name`, _), values) => values.head}.head
                          User(extractField("email"), extractField("password"))}    
                      .toList.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

request: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]] = Map(email[0] -> List(alice@example.com), 
email[1] -> List(bob@example.com), password[0] -> List(%vT*n7#4), password[1] -> List(Bfts7B&^))
defined class User
Field: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+)\[(\d+)\]
userList: List[User] = List(User(alice@example.com,%vT*n7#4), User(bob@example.com,Bfts7B&^))
```

Comment: +1, tasty. Not sure about the extractField bit, that needs to be abstracted away handling forms of any number of fields -- it's all String,String Maps so that shouldn't be a show stopper I don't think.

Comment: should mention that the form binder/validator handles the creation of case class instance, just have to pass it each form field row as Map[String, Seq[String]], the rest is taken care of